# Open in Command line doesn't work anymore since the last windows update

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry, prompt

Since the last Windows update (2013/11/12), this doesn't work anymore on Windows 7 64bit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\cmd]
@="Open cmd here"
"icon"=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,53,00,70,00,65,00,63,00,25,00,2c,00,30,\
  00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\cmd\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,53,00,70,00,65,00,63,00,25,00,20,00,20,00,2f,\
  00,6b,00,20,00,70,00,75,00,73,00,68,00,64,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,\
  00,00
```

Any idea why?

The two REG_EXPAND_SZ are:

```
%ComSpec%,0
```

and

```
%ComSpec%  /k pushd "%1"
```

The icon doesn't show any more, the "open cmd here" text is replaced by "cmd" in the right-click menu, and when clicked, Windows complains that no program is associated with this task.

Comment: Works ok here. What do you get when you open a cmd and type `set comspec`?

Comment: It should point to a valid cmd.exe (like `ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`).

Comment: The comspec is valid, and today it works.